# How to call function inside function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var abc = {
    'a': 10,
    'b': 10,
    c: function() {
        //like if I have many many functions in c
        init_a();
        multiple();

        function init_a() {
            abc.a = 30;
        }

        function multiple() {
            alert(abc.a * abc.b);
        }

        function minus() {
            alert(abc.a - abc.b);
        }
        return {
            function myalert() {
                var result = abc.a + abc.b;
                alert(result);
            }
        }
    },
    d: function() {
        abc.c.myalert(); // ???  error??
        abc.c().myalert(); // ??? error??  **it run all functions in c but not just myalert, strange things happening...
    }

}
abc.d();
```

whats the correct syntax to call the 'myalert()' function in function d?

Comment: There isnt one, and furthermore you're missing a closing brace `}` in there somewhere.

Comment: If you keep changing the code in your question, it makes it really difficult to give you a useful answer. I'll update my answer in the hopes that you're done updating your code.

Comment: Never mind. The current version contains a syntax error - you're defining your myalert function as a property of the returned object without defining an index. :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `myalert()` function <strike>is</strike>was local to `abc.c()`, so that's not possible.

You could let `c()` return `myalert()` though:

```
c: function() {
    return function myalert() {
      // whatever
    }
}, d: function() {
    this.c()()
}
```

Note that the returned function doesn't have to be named, i.e. `return function() { .. }`.

**Update**

If you want to call it like `this.c().myalert()`, then `c()` needs to return an object instead of the function directly:

```
c: function() {
    return {
        myalert: function() { ... }
    }
}
```

**Update 2**

Your `c()` function now contains other statements besides the declaration of `myalert()`. When called, `init_a()` and `multiple()` get called before it returns.

I would suggest refactoring your code, such as, move `myalert()` into the main object instead:

```
var abc = {
    a: 10,
    b: 10,
    c: function() { ... }
    myalert: function() { ... }
    d: function() {
        this.myalert();
    }
}
```

Comment: this.c()() ??? can't I give it a name? I want to distinguish the function is it able to this.c().myalert()?

Comment: strange, I used this.c().myalert() but in my code it actually run everything inside c, not just the reutrned my alert function but all other functions as well .

Comment: @FatDogMark Sorry to ask, but I need to know where you're trying to go with this, I need a concrete example.

Answer (score 2):

You can return an object from `c` that contains `myalert`:

```
var abc = {
    'c': function() {
        return {
            myalert: function() {
                alert('foo');
            }
        };
    },
    'd': function(){
        abc.c().myalert(); // foo
    }
};
abc.d();​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/g2KEK/

Answer (score 0):

```
c: function() {
    return {
        myalert : function() {
            // whatever
        }
    }
}, d: function() {
    this.c().myalert()
}
```